# jquery mobile changePage on form submit not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to change page on a form submit in Jquery, however, it is not working. It slides to show the same page instead of navigating to the target page. Below is the code. Any insights please? I tried using `"#mainpage"` , `"index.html#mainpage"` as well and still the same result. Link: [jsfiddle.net/7yRph/1](http://jsfiddle.net/7yRph/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>Multi-page template</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#launchpage').live('pagecreate',function(event) { 
        $('#fhome').submit( function () {
            $.mobile.changePage("mainpage");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 

<!-- PAGE: launchpage -->
<div data-role="page" id="launchpage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 data-theme="g" >Personal Details</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" >  
        <div class="content-primary">
        <form id="fhome" method="POST" >
            <div data-role="none">
                <p> Lets begin: </p>
            </div>
            <br/>           
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
                    <legend>Are you providing information about yourself?</legend>
                        <label for="launchradioyes">Yes</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="launchradioyes" value="yes" />
                        <label for="launchradiono">No</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="launchradiono" value="no" />
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Next" data-theme="a" />
            <br/>
         </form>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="d">

    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /launch page -->

<!-- PAGE: mainpage -->
<div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Testing page navigation II</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" >  
        <div class="content-primary">
            <div data-role="none">
             <label for="idprimary">ID:</label>
             <input type="tel" name="idprimary" id="idprimary" value="" />
            </div>
            <br/>           
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="d">
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page one -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is the example to test: http://jsfiddle.net/7yRph/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing your action attribute in your form tag.  This often breaks functionality of forms in browsers. Try this:

```
<form id="fhome" method="POST" action="mainpage">
```

It shouldn't negatively affect your code as you hijack the submit action anyway.

**UPDATE**

Also, you are missing your closing `</form>` tag and another closing `</div>` tag after that.

Do you need to use a submit button?  Would it work to use a button and its corresponding click event?

http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/7yRph/3/

**UPDATE 2**, working with form submit

After you resolve the closing tags, add the `preventDefault` method call and the `data-ajax="false"` attribute as outlined [here in the docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/forms-sample.html).

example: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/7yRph/9/

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and it still doesn't seem to work. I changed the code a bit to remove the script but the result is still the same! I also tried #mainpage in form action

Comment: Please see update, that might cause the weird issues you are experiencing, also probably need to use the '#' tag in the changePage event.

Comment: Tried that.. still the same :(

Comment: try that, will that work for your situation?  you can still work with the variables in the button click event and post them back through ajax or do whatever ever you need to do with them.

Comment: @Kiran, I also just found this better explination of the form submit requirements in the docs - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/forms-sample.html, in there it says the default is to submit via ajax which can't happen on its own page. This led me to my most recent update...

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I also missed the </div> closing tag which was failing on local machine..

Comment: You, sir, saved the day for me. I never would have thought of adding extra unused parameters to my form.

Answer (score 2):

When you hook `submit`, you should make sure the handler returns `false` (or call `preventDefault` on the event object), to prevent the default behavior of the submission.